# Server's maxconn parameter in haproxy

Tags: haproxy, concurrency

I'm using HAProxy in production to balance queries to a series of server instances that can only process 1 query at a time (by our own decision). Knowing that I set the maxconn parameter in the server definition line of backend configuration in haproxy.cfg file to 1, but the server still gets queries because I see in our server's log messages like "query rejected, already processing" and also in the HAProxy log queries that return to the client with a 502 http status code.

This is the HAProxy's configuration:

```
# this config needs haproxy-1.1.28 or haproxy-1.2.1

global
        log 127.0.0.1   local6 debug
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        stats socket /tmp/haproxy

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        balance roundrobin
        option httplog
        retries 10
        option  redispatch

frontend custom 0.0.0.0:50000
        backlog 2000
        acl p5queue avg_queue(custombe) gt 200
        tcp-request content reject if p5queue
        default_backend custombe
        timeout client  15000

backend custombe
        retries 10
        option redispatch
        timeout queue   600000
        timeout connect 1000
        timeout server  120000
        server  custom-server-1 0.0.0.0:50001 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-2 0.0.0.0:50002 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-3 0.0.0.0:50003 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-4 0.0.0.0:50004 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-5 0.0.0.0:50005 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-6 0.0.0.0:50006 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-7 0.0.0.0:50007 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-8 0.0.0.0:50008 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-9 0.0.0.0:50009 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
        server  custom-server-10 0.0.0.0:50010 weight 1 maxconn 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 1
```

Someone knows why the server instances get the queries when the maxconn parameter is set to one? I've read [StackOverflow's questions where the maxconn is explained and how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750518/difference-between-global-maxconn-and-server-maxconn-haproxy) in the different sections that's why I'm asking this now, it shouldn't work like this.

Comment: 'check'ing every 2 seconds creates another connection -- does your backend count those as queries?

Comment: Nope, because the queries must have some parameters to be counted as real queries.

Answer (score 1):

Make certain that there is no other process that has open connections to your service.

Take special note that during `haproxy reload`, there is a time frame in which two haproxy processes will use your resources, and each enforce connection limits on their own. The finishing process will not terminate before all queues are drained. Therefor, it is quite possible that the new process and its clients contend for seats.

The best workaround I can think of is to

1. Accept exactly two connections per worker process and
2. take care not to reload `haproxy` while a finishing process is still running.